How to remove spouse from our OR car title in Arkansas
Is it possible to sign a truck title that has mine and my spouse's name on it? The title states him OR me. I'm in Arkansas.

If you are in the process of getting divorced, talk to your attorney before you do anything with the title to the car.

If the title lists {you} OR {spouse} then only a single signature is required.
If the title lists {you} AND {spouse} then both signatures are required.
If the title does not list either words {OR} or {AND} then all states take the presumption that both signatures are required.

The last titled owner(s) of record must sign an application for duplicate title.  If jointly owned with owner names connected by “and” both must sign, if connected by “or” either may sign.  If a lien has been recorded and is still in effect, the lien holder may complete and sign a Permission to Issue a Replacement Title form, # 10-315, and the title will be mailed to the lien holder.  If the customer states that a recorded lien has been released, a lien release is required, in which case a notification will be sent to lien holder informing them that they have ten (10) business days to respond if the lien release is not valid.  If the lien holder does not respond within ten (10) business days, the title will be printed and provided to the owner.  If the lien holder responds that the lien release is not valid, the duplicate title will be mailed to the lien holder.  In addition to the above requirements, the applicant will need something to identify the vehicle, such as a vehicle registration certificate, a license plate number, a title number or the vehicle identification number. The cost for a replacement title is $10.00. Checks should be made payable to the Department of Finance and Administration.

In Arkansas, you want to ask for a "replacement title".
Disclaimer: I used to work for the Kentucky Transportation Cabinet (KY's version of department of motor vehicles plus highway department). American Association of Motor Vehicle Administrators is the trade association of agencies in USA, CA & MX for departments of motor vehicles.
